# CSS Hover Effect on 2 Overlapping Images Simultaneously

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create this hover effect using CSS only but can also use JavaScript if needed.

I was able to create the layout in HTML and effect a hover state on each image individually but not able to create a hover the effects both images at once and in opposite ways.

[Figma Prototype](https://www.figma.com/proto/oKODY7LwbOpa9vtScdWM5i/Hover-Effect?page-id=0%3A1&node-id=0%3A1&viewport=792%2C655%2C1&scaling=scale-down)

This is what I tried and it worked on each image individually but I need both images to change simultaneously.

```
    #wrap img {
    -webkit-transition: 400ms ease 100ms;
    -moz-transition: 400ms ease 100ms;
    transition: 400ms ease 100ms;
}
    
img.hvrimg1 {
    position:relative;
    bottom:180px;  
    left: 260px;
    z-index: 1;
 
}

img.hvrimg1:hover {
    position:relative;
    filter: blur(3px);
    -moz-transform: translate(-10px, -0px);
    -ms-transform: translate(-10px, -0px);
    -o-transform: translate(-10px, -0px);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-10px, -0px);
    transform: translate(-10px, -0px)

}
    
img.hvrimg2 {
    position:relative;
    filter: blur(3px);


}

img.hvrimg2:hover {
    position:relative;
    filter: blur(0px);
        -moz-transform: translate(10px, -0px);
    -ms-transform: translate(10px, -0px);
    -o-transform: translate(10px, -0px);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-10px, -0px);
    transform: translate(10px, -0px)

}
```

Comment: You have a container for all images, put the hover on the container then do what you need for each image

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Honestly I am a novice at CSS/HTML and not quite following what you're saying. I think you are saying add the hover to the container, which totally makes sense but the challenge is I need the two images to do two different things. On blurs in, the other blurs out and one moves to the left, and the other to the right. I got the motion and blur working individually but not at the same time.

Comment: Ok, I will write something in an answer that when you see it, a light bulb is going to light up and you will know exactly what to do

Comment: I figured it out. It's not perfect but it works as intended. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I am talking about

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

```
    <html>
<style type="text/css">
#wraphvrimg img {
    -webkit-transition: 400ms ease 100ms;
    -moz-transition: 400ms ease 100ms;
    transition: 400ms ease 100ms;
}
.section {
    background: #ffff;
    width: 850px;
    overflow: hidden
}
.section img.hvrimg1 {
    filter: blur(0px);
    position: relative;
    bottom: 180px;
    left: 20px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.section:hover img.hvrimg1 {
    filter: blur(3px);
    transform: translate(-20px, -0px)
}
.section img.hvrimg2 {
    filter: blur(3px);
    position: relative;
    right: 240px;
}
.section:hover img.hvrimg2 {
    filter: blur(0px);
    transform: translate(20px, 0px)
}
</style>
</head><body>
<div id="wraphvrimg" class="section"> <img src="Rectangle 5.png" alt="" width="411" height="253" class="hvrimg1"/> <img src="Rectangle 4.png" width="418" height="493" alt=""/ class="hvrimg2" > </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my example, `#wrap` is your image/parent container, and as you can see you can target each image on hover of the parent and you can do whatever you want to the image. I am sure you can figure out the rest from here.

```css
#wrap:hover .image-1 {
  color: red;
}

#wrap:hover .image-2 {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
   <div class="image-1">image 1</div>
   <div class="image-2">image 2</div>
</div>
```